# Type a phone number intent

Tags: java, android

How can I make my app type a given phone number without calling? I use:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

But that statement makes a call too.

Comment: Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);  Use this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `Intent.ACTION_CALL` with `Intent.ACTION_DIAL`

Answer (score 1):

You're using ACTION_CALL. You need to use ACTION_DIAL instead.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
startActivity(callIntent);
```